# lib to read java docs

Tags: java, parsing, reflection, javadoc

I'm working on a simple parser to transform java-interfaces and value objects to C#. This is done, so a C# client to communicate with the java JMS server can be created automatically.

My parser is almost finished, I can read generic-informatins, reuse C# types, and even merger getter and setter methods to properties. The only thing i can't, because it's not possible to be done with reflections, is to read the parameter names of methods in an interfaces. I found a library (BCEL) and can read the parameter names of "real" methods, in classes, but not within an interfaces.

So my idea was, eitherway it would be cool to have the former java comments also transfered into .net, so i could use it and i could use the very same tool to get the parameter names, since they can also read them.

So my question, do you know of any library which i could use for this? I have the generated javadocs and also the sourcecode which i could use as a source for the tool.

Thank you very much
cheers
zahorak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the source code, the easiest way would be to use a custom Javadoc doclet. This gets access to all the declarations (including parameter names), and also all comments. You can then convert it in any format you want.

If you only have the Javadoc output, I suppose most IDEs have some way of parsing it. Have a look at Eclipse or Netbeans, maybe their Javadoc parsing code is extractable.

Comment: Hi, thx for your fast response, i checked the javadoc doclets and i think they can do the trick; - Thanks for your help